# How to change in the laravel default cookie encryption to SHA-256 or SHA-512?

Tags: laravel, session, encryption, cookies

Laravel Default Encryption using AES-256 and AES-128 encryption. how we can change that to sha-256 or sha-512

Comment: AES is encryption, it means it is possible to get data back using the correct key. SHA is hash function - a one-way function scrambling the original content with no option to get the original content. So you cannot "switch" from AES to SHA. Question is, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you would change it it will be impossible to read the cookies ...

Comment: there is security team raised the issue for weak encryption that's why trying to change the default one

Comment: There's nothing stronger than AES-256 at this time. If that security team is so smart, why don't they recommend an alternative? Note that the algorithm is usually not the problem, the scheme and the system are much more likely suspects when it comes to finding weaknesses.